# database on SSD: data only or the DBM program too?

Tags: mac-osx, database, postgresql, ssd, sqlite

I plan on moving the data I use for statistical analysis (100-ish Gb) onto an SSD. The data is either sqlite single-file db's, or postgresql-managed data. The SSD is 240 Gb, 550 MB/s read and 520 MB/s write.

Should I reserve that space for the data only, or would it be a good idea to install the operating system (Mac OS X) and the application directory (Adobe Suite, Microsoft Office and the like) on the SSD too?

And would it make a substantial speed difference whether I also install the postgresql binaries on the SSD?

I have plenty of other space (another 300Gb hard-drive, and a 1Tb one). Don't know the features of the non-SSD drives, though they're our standard equipment on all Macs, and they're definitely OK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put postgresql on the SSD, it will start up faster, but since programs run in RAM (unless you're swapping) it won't make much difference while postgresql is running. (And if you're swapping, go buy some more RAM.) The same is true for any of your programs, as well as the operating system itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. you have the space for OS and Apps
2. It's a desktop machine that you care about the OS and app performance (booting, launching apps, etc.)

If those are true, then I would most certainly put the SSD in as the boot/primary partition drive, and only use the legacy disks for backups, archives, etc.  The overall performance difference of SSD is significant, not just in performance number, but in user experience (which is what you're asking about it seems).